# How to check the value of msword checkbox using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to tick and untick `MS Word` checkbox using powershell script. Using the below code I can only find the checkbox using bookmark. How to set the value for the checkbox? Please help!

```
$bookmark="bmMale"
If($Document.Bookmarks.Exists($bookmark)){
$bookmark="bmMale"
Write-Host "Found bookmark " $bookmark
$objRange = $Document.Bookmarks.Item($bookmark).Range
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Content Control, you can change it like this:

```
$winword = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application    
$winword.ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Item(1).Checked = $true
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for answer.but my check box is form field not content control. please suggest..

Comment: i Got it!!!  `$winword.ActiveDocument.Formfields.Item(1).Checkbox.value = $true`
Thanks for the hint. :)